# Renaming (.filename) file to original names

Tags: command-line, rename

I'm trying to revert a change I made via `rename`.

I was renaming files in a subfolder, then without thinking, tried to clear the `..` from names using:

```
rename "s/.././" *
```

Now I have a folder of 600 files with the 2 first letters of each filename changed to `.zzyGir*`

Is there any way to change the "." back to the first letters of each filename without losing the whole file?

I've tried different things with no luck, such as:

```
rename "s/./Di/; *
```

I'm open to one-file-at-a-time solutions, too, I'm primarily trying to avoid losing the files.

Comment: Reformatted question to more clearly identify the commands involved, and to reduce noise to make it easier to grok the details of the situation quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The first two letters are history. No chance to get them back. But you can rename the files to strip the leading `.` with the procedure below

Be sure to have the `bash` in a terminal

```
bash
```

Go into your folder with the wrong filenames

```
shopt -s dotglob
rename -n 's/^\./Di/' *
```

If all looks fine

```
rename 's/^\./Di/' *
```

Finish with

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

---

*Explanation*

- `rename -n "s/^\./Di/" *`

  - `-n`

    No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.
  - `/^\./`

    - `^` assert position at start of the string
    - `\.` matches the character `.` literally
- `shopt -s dotglob` & `shopt -u dotglob`

  - `shopt`

    ```
    shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname …]
    ```

    Toggle the values of settings controlling optional shell behavior.
  - `-s`

    Enable (set) each optname.
  - `-u`

    Disable (unset) each optname.
  - `dotglob`

    If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a `.` in the results of filename expansion.

---

*Example*

```
$ ls -oag
total 88
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Jul 17 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 226 86016 Jul 17 17:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Jul 17 17:16 .foo

$ rename "s/^\./Di/" *

$ ls -oag
total 88
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Jul 17 17:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 226 86016 Jul 17 17:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Jul 17 17:16 Difoo
```

---

I'm not sure, what you mean with this

> Is there any way to change the "." back to the first letters of each
>   filename

Do you mean something like this?

`.zzyGir` -> `zzzzGir`

If yes, then use this commands in a bash:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rename -n 's/^\.(..)(.*)/$1$1$2/' *
```

Check the results and rename with

```
rename 's/^\.(..)(.*)/$1$1$2/' *
```

And finally again

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Comment: +1, on a side note you don't have to enable `dotglob` to match dotfiles, you can just match them with this globbing pattern: `.*`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a folder with files such as below:

```
ls -la

drwxrwxr-x 2 ron ron 4096 Jul 17 20:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ron ron 4096 Jul 17 20:47 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 .abc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 .Gyr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 .hig123
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 .zyz
```

and you want to remove `.` from all the file names to make it:

```
abc
Gyr
hig123
zyz
```

For this you can use `find` and `rename`:

> `find . ! -path . -type f -name ".*" -exec rename -n "s/.\/.//" {} \;`

The above command (i.e with the `-n`) is a dry-run:

```
find . ! -path . -type f -name ".*" -exec rename -n "s/.\/.//" {} \;
rename(./.zyz, zyz)
rename(./.abc, abc)
rename(./.Gyr, Gyr)
rename(./.hig123, hig123)
```

Run it without `-n` to actually change the file names:

```
find . ! -path . -type f -name ".*" -exec rename "s/.\/.//" {} \;
ls -la
total 8   
drwxrwxr-x 2 ron ron 4096 Jul 17 20:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 ron ron 4096 Jul 17 20:47 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 abc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 Gyr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 hig123
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron    0 Jul 17 20:47 zyz
```